# printf ничего не выводит

Tags: c, массивы, память

Написал код вычисления произведения матриц, но он не выводит ответ. Проверяющая система пишет "ошибка выполнения, код завершения 139". Подскажите пожалуйста где вообще может быть ошибка, потому что я ее не вижу.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {
    int a1, a2, a3, a4;
    scanf ("%d%d%d%d", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4);
    if (a2 != a3) {
        printf("-1");
        return 0;
    }

    //создание матриц
    int **A = (int**)malloc(a1 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int ia = 0; ia < a2; ia++) {
        A[ia] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*a2);
    }


    int **B = (int**)malloc(a3 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int ib = 0; ib < a4; ib++) {
        A[ib] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*a4);
    }


    int **C = (int**)malloc(a1 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int ic = 0; ic < a1; ic++) {
        A[ic] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*a4);
    }

    //заполнение матриц
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < a2; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < a4; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &B[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //умножение
    for (i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < a4; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a2; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }  

    //вывод
    for (i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < a4; j++) {
            printf("%d", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //free
    for (i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
        free(A[i]);
        free(C[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < a3; i++) {
        free(B[i]);
    }
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);   
}
```

Comment: Это называется "писать код методом copy-paste". Вы стали жертвой этого метода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всякий раз, когда программа завершает свою работу по случаю возникновения сигнала она возвращает значение равное 128 плюс номер сигнала. В вашем случае это сигнал с номером 11, что, согласно таблице (см., например, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/ru/man7/signal.7.html ), означает SIGSEGV, то есть ошибка сегментирования, которая означает почти всегда то, что Вы вышли за границу массива. В каком месте Вы сделали такую ошибку лучше искать отладчиком, хотя можно и методом пристального вглядывания найти

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот, навскидку...

```
int **A = (int**)malloc(a1 * sizeof(int*));
for (int ia = 0; ia < a2; ia++) {
    A[ia] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*a2);
}
```

Выделяете память под `a1` указателей, затем инициализируете их `a2`... И что будет, если `a2` будет больше, чем `a1`? И это не единственное такое место...

**Update**

Похоже, нужно не только пропустить через мясорубку, но и пережевать, и проглотить...

```
int main ()
{
    int a1, a2, a3, a4;
    scanf ("%d%d%d%d", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4);
    if (a2 != a3) {
        printf("-1");
        return 0;
    }

    //создание матриц
    int **A = (int**)malloc(a1 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int ia = 0; ia < a1; ia++) {
        A[ia] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*a2);
    }


    int **B = (int**)malloc(a3 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int ib = 0; ib < a3; ib++) {
        B[ib] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*a4);
    }


    int **C = (int**)malloc(a1 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int ic = 0; ic < a1; ic++) {
        C[ic] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*a4);
    }

    //заполнение матриц
    for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a2; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a4; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &B[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //умножение
    for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a4; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a2; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //вывод
    for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a4; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //free
    for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
        free(A[i]);
        free(C[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a3; i++) {
        free(B[i]);
    }
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, если памяти не хватает так как я написал, то по идее с запасом хватит так:
`int **A = (int**)malloc(a1 * sizeof(int*) * a2);`

Comment: Но и это не сработало.

Comment: Конечно. Это же далеко не все. Например, вы собираетесь инициализировать `B[i]` или оставляете это Страуструпу? :) А инициализацию `C[i]` - Ритчи? :) Забирайте. Но это уже - простите, с вашей стороны - полная беспомощность...